# Angular Material Angular 5 set Mat-Select value in code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

I have a test that tests several Angular Material mat-select drop-downs.  For normal select drop-downs I was able to set the value using

```
productsSelectEl.nativeElement.value = 1;
```

I know this can be done using an NgModel but is there any way to do it without having to use an NgModel? This is because the more select drop-downs I have then I have to manage those extra variables which I don't actually need.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

Using Reactive Forms:

```
this.theNameOfYourFormGroup.controls.theNameOfYourFormControl.setValue(1);
```